# 404 Laravel 8 хотя маршрут есть

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

я пытался сделать регистрацию на Laravel 8 с помощью Laravel ui по книге Дронова, но при переходе по http://127.0.0.1:8000/login выдает ошибку 404 | NOT FOUND.

web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\BbsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ContactController;

Route::get('/', [BbsController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
Route::get('/contact', [BbsController::class, 'contact']);

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/{bb}', 'BbsController@detail')->name('detail');
```

HomeController.php - https://pastebin.com/beYb6uts

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а где во всем этом у вас слово `login` искать?

Comment: @teran `Auth::routes();` обычно добавляет ряд роутов, а именно: Authentication Routes (login, logout), Registration Routes и Password Reset Routes.

Comment: @Simon это я догадался, но какую роль тут играет упомянутый HomeController ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`composer require laravel/ui`
`php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`